# MMB to rotate perpendicular to view

Tags: 3d-view

Is there a way for the middle mouse button to rotate the object perpendicular to view? Currently, no matter which angle my view is at, when I press and hold my MMB to rotate, the object will rotate along the Z-Axis.

I’ve been a Solidworks user previously and hope to change the rotate to similar. I believe it should be a setting but I’ve already tried most and it doesn’t work. I’ve search the net for the answer and nothing seem to work. Please help me, new user to Blender.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Edit, Performances, select Keymap, on the top you will see a seach bar, type "rotate" and you will find the key map for rotation of the object.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be looking for this setting, rotate around selection, in *Edit > Preferences*

[image]